# Display duplicate SQL column in PHP

Tags: php, sql

How would I display only duplicate last names in a column? This is what I have in my function so far.

```
 $query="SELECT first_name, last_name, suffix, city, state, birth, death from president WHERE COUNT last_name >'1' order by last_name;";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT lastname, COUNT(*)
FROM president
GROUP BY lastname
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```